# Input Field Numeric Value Formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, number-formatting

I am trying to have the input field auto format with the commas on hundreds, thousands etc.

I have tried the below the final data does get formatted but results in x.00 And the input field does not show any formatting at all.

**Can this be done without adding a state to the component?**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { TextInput, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { DataContext } from "../context/DataContext";

let inputValue;


const InputForm = ({ name }) => {

  const { updateData } = useContext(DataContext)
  const handleChangeText = (text) => {
   // Remove any non-numeric characters from the input
  const numericValue = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
  // Remove any existing commas from the numeric value
  const withoutCommas = numericValue.replace(/,/g, "");
  // Parse the numeric value as a floating-point number
  const parsedValue = parseFloat(withoutCommas);

  // Format the parsed value with commas for thousands separators and two decimal places
  const formattedValue = parsedValue.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  });

  console.log(formattedValue);
  inputValue = formattedValue;
  }

  console.log("inputform")
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value= {0.00}
        onChangeText={handleChangeText}
        onEndEditing={() => {
          updateData(inputValue, name)
        }}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 20,
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default React.memo(InputForm);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TextInput, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { DataContext } from "../context/DataContext";

const InputForm = ({ name }) => {
  const { updateData } = useContext(DataContext);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleEndEditing = () => {
    const inputValue = inputRef.current.value;
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    const formattedValue = parsedValue.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    });
    inputRef.current.value = formattedValue;
    updateData(formattedValue, name);
  };

  console.log("inputform");
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <TextInput
        ref={inputRef}
        style={styles.input}
        defaultValue="0.00"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onBlur={handleEndEditing}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 20,
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default React.memo(InputForm);
```

- We added a ref to the TextInput component using the useRef hook. The
  ref is assigned to inputRef.
- By using the defaultValue prop instead of value and updating the
  value via the inputRef.current.value, we can maintain the formatting
  in the input field without adding state to the component.